# Performing WKWebview loadrequest inside NSURLSession Completion handler

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I'm trying to to do loadrequest WKWebview inside NSURLSession Completion handler
but i'm having problem because it has to be in the main thread i need it inside the completion block? BTW, i was able to accomplish this with NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest but i don't want to use that depracted api.

```
- (void)tryServePage {

   // cant call main thread here
   NSString *localNodeServerURL = @"http:/127.0.0.1/";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:localNodeServerURL];
   [[NSURLSession alloc] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable myData, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

       BOOL reachable;
       if (myData) {
           reachable=YES;
       } else {
           reachable=NO;
       }

       // now call ourselves back on the main thread
       dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if(!reachable) {
               [self tryServePage];
           } else {
               NSString *localNodeServerURL = @"http:/127.0.0.1/";
               NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:localNodeServerURL];
               NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
               [self->_myWebView loadRequest:request];
           }
       });
   }];
    
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do here, but it seems you are retrieving the content of a URL just to check if it is reachable. If it is, you ask the WebView to retrieve that content again, which seems inefficient to me. You should take a look at other APIs such as the `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` function to accomplish this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1514924-scnetworkreachabilitygetflags?language=objc

Comment: i tried that before but it always return true, i don't know which flag should i use and i thought since it's localhost, reachbility may not apply. i was able to resolve this using performSelectorOnMainthread but still it was not the proper solution. what i'm trying to accomplish here is to load a local web service immediately as soon as it becomes available. The function is in a loop as long as the service is not available, that's why its calling itself in the function tryServePage.

Comment: You could instead add a `WKNavigationDelegate` on your webView and use the `webView:didFailNavigation:withError:` to create the loop. You try to load your resource in the webView. If it fails, the webView will call your delegate's `webView:didFailNavigation:withError:` where you can try again. This will loop until succes, where the webView will call `webView:didFinishNavigation:` instead.

Comment: I'll check on webView:didFailNavigation:withError, but it might not work too cause I'm already rendering a loading page in the webview while the service is not up yet.